# Converting nonlinear ODE with neumann BC into Fredholm integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, integral-equations

I have a nonlinear ODE I wish to convert into a Fredholm integral equation. [This site](https://gauravtiwari.org/changing-differential-equations-into-integral-equations/) shows how to convert an ODE with Dirichlet BC into an integral equation, however I cannot figure out how to do it with Neumann BC.

My equation is of the form

$u''(x)+f(x,u)u=0$

With BC

$u'(0)=u'(L)=0$

I've tried following the linked site. Begin by integrating

$\int_0^x u''(x)dx=\int_0^xf(x,u(x))u(x)dx$

$u'(x)-u'(0)=\int_0^xf(x,u(x))u(x)dx$

Here the derivation deviates from the linked site with $u'(0)=0$. Integrate again

$u(x)-u(0)=\iint_0^xf(x,u(x))u(x)dx$

$u(x)-u(0)=\int_0^x(L-t)f(t,u(t))u(t)dt$

Where the rule for reducing multiple integrals was used (by the way, does anyone know if that rule has a name?).

From here I just get stuck. I'm not sure where to go from here or if this method is even the correct approach for neumann BC.

EDIT: After more thinking it seems if I go back to this step

$u'(x)-u'(0)=\int_0^xf(x,u(x))u(x)dx$

And then evaluate the integral out to L

$u'(L)=\int_0^Lf(x,u(x))u(x)dx$

The derivative at L is also zero, and hence I get

$0=\int_0^Lf(x,u(x))u(x)dx$

Does this look correct?